# What definition is NIST using for GR&R level 1 and 2 standard deviations?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation, msa

Reviewing the NIST/SEMATECH e-Handbook of Statistical Methods, http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/ for information on Gauge Repeatability and Reproducibility studies (GR&R) I came across a definition of standard deviation and I'm having a hard time equating it to $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(x-\mathbb{E}[x])^2]}$ .

From https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/mpc/section4/mpc431.htm

"Choose at least Q=10 work pieces or check standards, which are essentially identical insofar as their expected responses to the measurement method. Measure each of the check standards twice with the same gauge, being careful to randomize the order of the check standards.

After about a month, repeat the measurement sequence, randomizing anew the order in which the check standards are measured. Measurements on the check standards are designated:
$Y_{1,1} , Y_{2,1} , Y_{1,2} , Y_{2,2}$
with the first index identifying the month of measurement and the second index identifying the repetition number.

The level-1 standard deviation, which describes the basic precision of the gauge, is

$s_1=\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{1}{4Q}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{Q}{(Y_{1,1}−Y_{1,2})^2+(Y_{2,1}−Y_{2,2})^2}}$ ,
with $ν_1=2Q$ degrees of freedom.

The level-2 standard deviation, which describes the variability of the measurement process over time, is

$s_2=\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{1}{Q}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{Q}\left(\frac{(Y_{1,1}+Y_{1,2})−(Y_{2,1}+Y_{2,2})}{2}\right)^2}$,
with $ν_2=Q$ degrees of freedom. "

Since I don't recognize these std deviations my first thought is they are simplified forms of $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(x-\mathbb{E}[x])^2]}$

If $\mathbb{E}[Y_{1,1}]=\mathbb{E}[Y_{1,2}]=\mathbb{E}[Y_{2,1}]=\mathbb{E}[Y_{2,2}]$ for each $Y$ (because the check standards are stated to be identical), then $s_2$ is the std dev of the difference between the means of the repeated check standard measurements month to month.

$s_1$ looks like the std dev of the difference between each repeated measurement (as if the measurements taken months apart were taken at the same time) but where is the $\frac{1}{4}$ coming from? if you sum up $2Q$ squared differences then why divide by $4Q$? Its as if each measurement contributes a degree of freedom for $4Q$ degrees of freedom but NIST states only $2Q$ degrees of freedom.

Does anybody recognize how NIST derived these standard deviations?

(P.S. I realize NIST failed to include the index in their summations. I copied the information here as it is presented for convenience)